# Is this a hosting/database issue not an EE issue?

Tags: low-variables

I just want to confirm that the interminttant issues on this site not rendering (blank page) and this error are related to web hosting and not EE/Low Variables 2.3.4:

```
Error Number: 1

Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_a34_0.MYI' (Errcode: 28)

SELECT `ee`.`variable_name`, `ee`.`variable_data` FROM (`exp_global_variables` AS ee) JOIN `exp_low_variables` AS low ON `ee`.`variable_id` = `low`.`variable_id` WHERE `ee`.`site_id` = '1' AND `low`.`early_parsing` = 'y' ORDER BY `low`.`group_id`, `low`.`variable_order`

Filename: third_party/low_variables/ext.low_variables.php

Line Number: 323
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes. You need to make your temp directory writeable. If you are on shared hosting, you should contact your host about this.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. That's exactly what I thought. I have contacted the client so they can follow up with their web host. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_a34_0.MYI' (Errcode: 28)
```

"[**Errcode: 28**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cannot-create.html)" means MYSQL can't write to the tmp directory because it is full. You'll need to contact the host to have them fix the issue.